# installing windows on ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a bootable usb but when I try to install it using it, I do not get the option to boot from the usb but from the cd rom. Can someone help me with the steps or the commands ? By the way it is my back up laptop and I have forgotten the password for Ubuntu. Let me know if you can still help.

It is an old hp laptop, legacy mode is what was used, i think. it uses MBR. I have Ubuntu with Linux 5.0 installed on it and whenever I turn it on it takes me to the gnu grub version 2.02 page and gives me three options :  1) Ubuntu , 2) advanced options for ubuntu and 3) system set up.          In system set up , I was able to find boot options but even when I selected f9 ( boot device option ) it would not recognize the bootable usb that was inserted. So is there a way to get windows on the laptop?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in Legacy (Compatibility Mode) or UEFI mode?  Asking if your using MBR or GPT? You can edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: It is an old hp laptop, legacy mode is what was used, i think. it uses MBR. I have Ubuntu with Linux 5.0 installed on it and whenever I turn it on it takes me to the gnu grub version 2.02 page and gives me three options :

Comment: Make sure your booting to the installation media with UEFI mode disabled.  If it still doesn’t work recreate the installation media

Comment: I enabled legacy support in system configuration, I enabled cd rom boot and disabled internal network adapter boot. Then saved and exited while having the usb plugged in. IT took me back to gnu grub page but still no option to install windows from the bootable usb. I turn it off and turn it back on and it took me to the gnu grub page once more. I would not mind recreating the installation media however the laptop that I created it on is able to see the files on it and it seems to be working on that laptop but the old one with Ubuntu on it does not seem to be able to ue the bootable usb.

Comment: Just to confirm, since all your vital information is in a comment, after you enable Legacy/CSM/Compatibility Mode you changed the boot order of your device?  You made sure the media your attempting to use supports Compatibility Mode?  Did you create the ISO your using with the Media Creation Tool?

Comment: I am new ro using the forum. Is there a way to have an instant message chat session ? or is exchanging contact information against the rules ? If  it is not against the rules then I would be ok using google hang out or another form of  instant messenger.

Comment: I absolutely never offer help privately.